# HDFS client dial tcp: lookup xxx(my hostname) on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

Tags: go, hdfs

I'm using a golang lib(https://github.com/colinmarc/hdfs) to interact with my HDFS.

When I use `client.CopyToRemote(src, dest)` to copy local files to remote HDFS, sometimes got this error when running the code in a docker container with bridge network mode.

It is confusing me because I construct the client with IP address not hostname like this:

```
client, err := hdfs.NewClient(hdfs.ClientOptions{
        Addresses: ["41.51.123.51:9000"],
        User:      "hdfs",
    })
```

Why is it dialing the hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, it is dialing the `datanode` with the `hostname`.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/colinmarc/hdfs/pull/138) talking about this.

After I set this option `UseDatanodeHostname: false`, the error is gone.